# Calculate Laplace transform of the product of t and f(t) by differenitating f(t) (5.5-4)

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, solution-verification

**Request**:

Please check my work. State where errors, if any, occurred and how to correct them. Is there a better way to calculate the transform other than the present method given?

**Given**:

Find the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot \sin(3t)\}$ by differentiating $f(t)$.

**Solution**:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot f(t)\}=-F'(s)$$

$$f(t)=\sin(3t)$$

$$F(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+9}$$

$$F'(s)=\frac{s\cdot(-1)\cdot2s}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{1}{(s^2+9)}=-\frac{2s^2}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{1}{(s^2+9)}$$

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot \sin(3t)\}=-F'(s)=\frac{2s^2}{(s^2+9)^2}-\frac{1}{(s^2+9)}$$

Comment: The final answer should be $ \frac{6s}{(s^2+9)^2} $. So try to simplify and compare the two answers.

Comment: @science Please have a second look at my problem. I accidentally called my function $t\cdot cos(3t)$ when it should have been written $t\cdot sin(3t)$.

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering the Laplace transform of $\cos(3t)$ while you should consider the Laplace transform of $\sin(3t)$

> $$ F(s) = \frac{3}{s^2+9}. $$

Comment: Thank you for corrections. At first I had written the wrong function and corrected it but I had forgotten to also correct the initial transform. The actual problem was to find the Laplace transform of $t\cdot sin(3t)$. For that I get $\frac{6s}{(s^2+9)^2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @JulesManson: You are welcome! Yes it is a correct answer!